# How to get all categories in configuration (system.xml). magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, backend

I'm getting all the categories in `system.xml` using

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Category implements ArrayInterface{

    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_categoryCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->_categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    }

    /**
    * Get category collection
    *
    * @param bool $isActive
    * @param bool|int $level
    * @param bool|string $sortBy
    * @param bool|int $pageSize
    * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection or array
    */


    public function getCategoryCollection($isActive = true, $level = false, $sortBy = false, $pageSize = false)
    {
        $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        // select only active categories
        if ($isActive) {
            $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        }

        // select categories of certain level
        if ($level) {
            $collection->addLevelFilter($level);
        }

        // sort categories by some value
        if ($sortBy) {
            $collection->addOrderField($sortBy);
        }

        // select certain number of categories
        if ($pageSize) {
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        }

        return $collection;
    }



    public function toOptionArray(){

        $arr = $this->_toArray();
        $ret = [];
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
            $ret[] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value
            ];
        }    
        return $ret;
    }




    private function _toArray(){

        $categories = $this->getCategoryCollection(true, false, false, false);
        $catagoryList = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category){
           $catagoryList[$category->getEntityId()] = __($this->_getParentName($category->getPath()) . $category->getName());
        }
        return $catagoryList;
    }



    private function _getParentName($path = ''){
        $parentName = '';
        $rootCats = array(1,2);  
        $catTree = explode("/", $path);
        array_pop($catTree);     
        if($catTree && (count($catTree) > count($rootCats))){
            foreach ($catTree as $catId){
                if(!in_array($catId, $rootCats)){
                    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($catId);
                    $categoryName = $category->getName();
                    $parentName .= $categoryName . ' -> ';
                }
            }
        }
        return $parentName;
    }
}
```

but when I submit my **extension** to **magento QA** then they give me the **error**[image]
now how can I solve this? they are saying that I'm duplicating the class the which core class I can use to get all categories like that
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try not to use a **"core-like"** class name. I doubt, it is because you named your class as **Category** which is already present in the Magento core.

You can change it to something like **Catlist** at least it doesn't seem to duplicate any existing core class and instead more like what it seems to, which is **Category list**.

Comment: didn't you think that we use many classes with the same name like `Data.php` (Helper) and many more.. but they didn't give me any error on that class

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I got your point. But having read the review results there's no way you can solve it with a plugin. Just my thought